# how to call function-1 inside function-2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function-1

```
$('.make_favorite').live('click', function() {
  //some code here
});
```

I have another function-2

```
function selectContactTab() {
  //some code here
  //call function-1 here
}
```

for some reason I do not have control over function-1,
My Question is how to call function-1 inside function-2?

Comment: Have you checked trigger click event?

Comment: What old version of jQuery are you using that it supports `live`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually fire the click event, which will result in the anonymous function, what you state as `Function-1`, being run...

```
function selectContactTab() {
  //some code here
  //call function-1 here
  $('.make_favorite').click();
}
```

Comment: it produced "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: This error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` means that you're triggering an infinite loop which in turn causes a stack overflow. Probably the click event is triggering itself an infinitely number of times. I'd need to see more code to be able to help with this error.

Comment: thanks @bastos.sergio there was something wrong with my code, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Function-1` is actually function call, with a callback passed in. You need to wrap it inside it's own function, something like this:

```
function functionOne() {
  //some code here
}

function selectContactTab() {
  //some code here
  functionOne();
}

$('.make_favorite').live('click', functionOne);
```

In this example, `functionOne` is a function on the scope, and is also being passed in as the callback for your `.live` call. The reason it didn't work before was because the callback in your `function-1` was outside of the scope your `function-2` was in - put simply, it didn't exist. Initialising it in a function like in my example will make it available to call.

Comment: In your first example, the call to `selectContactTab()` will only define a new callback and won't run anything...

Comment: Ah, I was unfamiliar with the `.live()` method - I'll remove the first example

Comment: My function-1 is some function inside some plugin so I don't have any control on it and I can not pass it to the .live call.

Comment: My function-1 is some function inside some plugin so I don't have any control on it and I can not pass any function to its .live call.

Comment: The function inside the `.live` call, as it is written now, only ever exists when that call is being made. If you don't/can't change it, it cannot be called from anywhere else